# db_select send me all the values and not what I want

Tags: php, mysql, database, drupal, drupal-7

What I want is to check if variables = variables AND timestamp > timestamp and if this are true delete the old value and create the new I think the above code just create all the values as it do not deletes the old one. How can I delete the old one while I create the new?

```
$query = db_select('watchdog', 'th')
    ->extend('PagerDefault')
    ->orderBy('wid')
    ->fields('th', array('variables', 'type', 'severity',
         'message', 'wid', 'timestamp'))
    ->limit(2000);

  // Fetch the result set.
  $result = $query -> execute();

  // Loop through each item and add to $row.
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    blabla($row);
  }


  function blabla($row)
    $timestamp = $row -> timestamp;
    $r = db_select('distinct', 'b')
      ->fields('b')
      ->condition('variables', $variables, '=')
      ->condition('timestamp', $timestamp, '>')
      ->execute();
    if($r -> rowCount() == 0) {
    $query = db_delete('error_log_jira')
      ->fields('b', array('timestamp', 'wid', 'variables',))
      ->execute();
    $query = db_insert('distinct')
      ->fields(array(
        'timestamp' => $timestamp,
        'wid' => $wid,
        'variables' => $variables,
     ))
     ->execute();
    }
```

This code works perfect

```
$r = db_select('blabla', 'b')
      ->fields('b')
      ->condition('variables', $variables, '=')
      ->execute();
```

Comment: There is no such function in php as db_select()

Did you think of this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90944/custom-module-db-select-title-and-body, which in this case, you are in wrong section of stackoverflow.

Comment: I updated my code you might can help me now!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `<` (lower than) instead of `>` (greater than) in your code example.

```
$r = db_select('blabla', 'b')
  ->fields('b')
  ->condition('variables', $variables, '=')
  ->condition('timestamp', $timestamp, '>')
  ->execute();
```

If you want to debug and view the executed query, you can make use of the `dpq()` function (part of the devel module) : https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpq/7

Comment: If i use < it show me the values as if  i do not use this line of code and if i use > it shows me all the values of the table i cannot understand what it it doing :'( :'(

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with your `$timestamp` value, what is it? How do you get the timestamp?

Comment: I updated the code i think that i have error in db_delete function